# How to remove vertical Line from html table?

Tags: html, css

Hi i want to remove vertical line from html table and only specific vertical line want to remove in my html table there  are only  3 vertical line where i want to remove 1 and 3 line only

Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.table1{

 background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, #003471, #448CCB);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#003471), to(#448CCB));

}
table, th, td {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="div1" class='display'>

           <table  width="100%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bordercolor='66A8FF'>
           <tr class="table1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
           <td  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text1</font></td>   
           <td  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text2</font></td>
            <td  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text3</font></td>  
             <td  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text4</font></td>   
            </tr>
            <tr class="table1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
           <td  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text1</font></td>   
           <td  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text2</font></td>
            <td  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text3</font></td>  
             <td  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text4</font></td>   
            </tr>
            </table>
               </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/URQM2/)

How can i achieve my out

Thanks in advance

Comment: you take 2x4 table try 2x2 table.you will get your output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Img]here is your code as you asked

```
     <div id="div1" class='display'>

       <table  width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor='66A8FF'>
       <tr class="table1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
       <td   width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text1</font></td>   
       <td class="remove_line"  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text2</font></td>
        <td  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text3</font></td>  
         <td class="remove_line1"  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text4</font></td>   
        </tr>
        <tr class="table1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
       <td  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text1</font></td>   
       <td class="remove_line"  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text2</font></td>
        <td  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text3</font></td>  
         <td  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text4</font></td>   
        </tr>
        </table>
           </div>
```

**and CSS for this**

```
.table1{

 background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, #003471, #448CCB);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#003471), to(#448CCB));

 }
table, th, td {

}
.remove_line{
border-right:2px solid red;    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/URQM2/12/)

Use the CSS:

```
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td:nth-child(2){
    border-right:1px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if SW4 got what you want, but I have some other notes:

- Put as much into CSS as possible. This makes it a lot easier to read and change your code.
- Override standard tags with care. You might want to have different table classes. So rather use `.table1 td` than `td`. I think only a css reset should override tags
- Consistent identation makes your code easier to read. I use [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to reindent code like yours.
- External CSS style sheet files like [described here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) help you to make it even easier to read your files.
- Have a look at [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

### CSS

```
.table1{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, #003471, #448CCB);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#003471), to(#448CCB));
    border: 1px solid #66A8FF;
}

table, th, td {
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}

td {
    font-size:28px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 48px;
}

table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

td:nth-child(2){
    border-right:1px solid white;
}
```

### HTML

```
<table  width="100%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
    <tr class="table1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
        <td  width="25%">Text1</td>
        <td  width="25%">Text2</td>
        <td  width="25%">Text3</td>
        <td  width="25%">Text4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
        <td  width="25%">Text1</td>
        <td  width="25%">Text2</td>
        <td  width="25%">Text3</td>
        <td  width="25%">Text4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/MartinThoma/B6WZY/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set class for second td And appy the border-right:2px solid #FFF.

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.table1{

 background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, #003471, #448CCB);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#003471), to(#448CCB));

}
table, th, td {

  border-right: none;
}
.set_border
{
border-right:3px solid #FFF;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="div1" class='display'>

           <table  width="100%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor='66A8FF'>
           <tr class="table1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
           <td  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text1</font></td>   
           <td  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px" class="set_border"><font color="#fff">Text2</font></td>
            <td  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px" ><font color="#fff">Text3</font></td>  
             <td  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text4</font></td>   
            </tr>
            <tr class="table1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
           <td  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text1</font></td>   
           <td  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px" class="set_border"><font color="#fff">Text2</font></td>
            <td  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text3</font></td>  
             <td  width="25%"  height="48px" align="center" style="font-size:28px"><font color="#fff">Text4</font></td>   
            </tr>
            </table>
               </div>
</body>
</html>
```